# Impossible to install .msi programs after hard drive removal

Tags: powershell, window, windows-installer, registry

I'm facing a problem that I can't find a solution. I'm running Windows 11 and after an hard drive crash, I had to install an other one (letter P:/ is not labeled anymore). Since then I'm **unable** to **proceed any .msi packages installations**. Even if I try to change the drive location, it throws this error :

[image]

Any idea on how to get rid of this ? Could it be registry related ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: To be honest StackOverflow probably isn't the right place to post this. I would recommend either [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)